# jQuery only works when "inspecting the element"?

Tags: jquery

I have this simple jQuery function that toggles a div with extra info. But it only works when I inspect the element whether through Chrome or Firefox. I inspected to see if the classes were being targeted correctly is how I found out (when it just worked out of the blue. ) But doesn't work without the inspect widow open.

Using jQuery version 1.11.0

my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $(".but-proj-highlights").click( function(){

         if ($(this).hasClass("isUp") ) {
         $(this).next("#project-highlights").animate({marginTop:"50%"}, 200);           
         $(this).removeClass("isUp");
    } else {
        $(this).next("#project-highlights").animate({marginTop:"-100%"}, 200);  
        $(this).addClass("isUp");
    }

    });
});// END
```

Html

```
<div class="but-proj-highlights isUp">
        Project Highlights
</div><!-- but proj highlights -->

<div id="project-highlights">
    <div class="entry-content">
        <h2>Project Highlights</h2>
        <?php echo  $projHighlights ?>
    </div><!-- entry-contnet -->
</div><!-- project highlights -->
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qwzb3an8/

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work fine.

Comment: The Fiddle works for me, too. Did you check your settings? e.g. Javascript disabled or something? Did you clear your cache?

Comment: FYI: I made the fiddle from his posted code.

Comment: @NathanTaylor, thanks. Fiddle works, but still doesn't work on any of my browsers Unless I am currently inspecting the element through the browser.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `animate` function is asynchronous so you'd want to wait until it's finished before doing `remove/add` class.

ex:

```
$(this).next("#project-highlights").animate({marginTop:"50%"}, 200, function () {
    // animate is complete
    $(this).removeClass("isUp");
});
```

Comment: Actually it's better without the callback. If you click it during the animation it will revert the animation after it's completed. In your solution this "feature" would break.

Comment: @Vic , Even when I remove the removeClass, to get the first click, it still doesn't work unless my Inspector Window is open. I also have a slider on that page, which I disabled to test, but nothing else.